# Show Cantor function is continuous using sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

To construct the Cantor set, $C$:

Define $J_{1,1}:= (1/3,2/3)$. And define $J_{2,1}:= (1/9, 2/9)$ and $J_{2,2}:= (7/9,8/9)$. Continue to get sets $J_{n,k}$ and define:

$K_1 = [0,1] \setminus J_{1,1}$.
$K_2= K_1\setminus (J_{2,1} \cup J_{2,2})$.

$\dots K_n= K_{n-1} \setminus (J_{n,1} \cup \dots \cup J_{n,2^{n-1}})$.

Then $$C = \bigcap_{n \in\mathbb{N}} K_n =[0,1] \setminus (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} J_{n,k}). $$
Let $K := (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} J_{n,k})$.

- For $x \in J_{n,1}$ let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2^n}$.
- For $x \in J_{n,2}$ let $f(x) = \frac{3}{2^n}$.
- $\dots$
- For $x \in J_{n,2^{n-1}}$ let $f(x) = \frac{2^n -1}{2^n}$.

Now the problem:
Let $x_0 \in C$. Then $$\lim_{K \ni x\to x_0} f(x)$$ exists.
I think that I can prove this by proving that $f$ has a continuous extension, $g$ to $[0,1]$. Then since $g$ is continuous for all $\{x_n\} \to x_0$, we have that $g(x_n) \to g(x_0)$. If $x_n$ is a sequence in $K$ then $g(x_n) = f(x_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am not sure if this is correct and I would prefer to prove it using the $\varepsilon - \delta$ limit definition.

Comment: what is $f$ here?@user124104

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that!